# Importing GeoTIFF into PostGIS without raster2pgsql?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, postgis-raster

I know that one can import GeoTIFF into PostGIS via `raster2pgsql`. I was wondering if there is any easy way (as a sequence of SQL statements) to do the same without resorting to the command line tool?

Essentially, I am interested in a PostgreSQL function that is the inverse of [ST_AsTIFF](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AsTIFF.html), which given a pathname to a GeoTIFF, creates a pgraster table or a row in such a table.

The reason I ask is that I need such a function in a SQL stored procedure to import and process GeoTIFFs (not known in advance).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at ST_FromGDALRAster.

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_FromGDALRaster.html

Though that function assumes you imported the GTIFF as a bytea in PostgreSQL.  If you want to keep the file out of the database and you have out-db enabled for your raster, you can use ST_AddBand.  There is an example of an out-db tiff on the reference of this page:

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_AddBand.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know of some example code for the first approach? I tried the second approach in PostGIS 2.1, but it didn't work. I think there is a bug in `ST_AddBand` which prevented it from correctly figuring out the size of an external geotiff.

Comment: Yah I have a feeling there is no logic in that for figuring out extent of geotiff, which is why the example fills it in.  Regarding the first. Not sure if this helps much - but another example: http://www.bostongis.com/blog/index.php?/archives/214-Waiting-for-PostGIS-2.1-ST_FromGDALRaster-free-those-images.html

Comment: I forgot to add, which may be your issue -- pulling the geotiff into the db with just stored proc is tricky.  You can try PL/Python or PL/Perl or some lang that can access the OS - doing reverse of this: http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_PLPython  or use pg_read_binary_file (essentially repurposing it)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048649/postgresql-9-x-pg-read-binary-file-inserting-files-into-bytea